# putting multiple arrays into one single ListBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I am trying to put multi arrays into a single listbox. Below is the code. It works well when I make every output go into its own listBox but I am trying to but them all in one listbox with the current headings. Can someone help? One last thing, I would also like the duplicate values to go into another column but don't know how. All I can due is just eliminate the duplicates (want to go above and beyond and show what numbers were eliminated)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim randomNum As New Random()
    Dim SampleArray(19) As Integer
    Dim aryNums() As Integer = SampleArray
    Dim distinctNums = SampleArray.Distinct()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        ListBox3.Items.Clear()

        For i = 0 To 19
            SampleArray(i) = randomNum.Next(10, 100)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(SampleArray(i).ToString)
        Next
        Array.Sort(SampleArray)
        For i = 0 To SampleArray.GetUpperBound(0)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(SampleArray(i))
        Next
        For Each num In distinctNums
            ListBox3.Items.Add(num.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox4.Items.Add("Index" & vbTab & "Random" & vbTab & "Sorted" & vbTab & "Unique")
        For i = 0 To 19
            SampleArray(i) = randomNum.Next(10, 100)
            ListBox4.Items.Add(i & vbTab & SampleArray(i).ToString)
            'ListBox4.Items.Add(SampleArray(i).ToString)
        Next
        Array.Sort(SampleArray)
        For i = 0 To SampleArray.GetUpperBound(0)
            ListBox4.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & SampleArray(i))
        Next
        For Each num In distinctNums
            ListBox4.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & num.ToString())
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please format this into something actually readable.

Comment: here is the whole code

Comment: You might be better off processing everything first rather than making multiple passes at the list box.  Process the arrays, create the result string, maybe store it in a List(Of String) then post the results to the listbox.  Also, your second loop posts `SampleArray(i)` which seems to be missing `.ToString`.

Comment: the problem is that I can not go above or below the "Next" word. when I do it says that it is not declaried when it is

Comment: Button1 works perfect. Thying to get button2 to display the way I want into a listbox. Want heading of "Index, Random, Sorted, Unigue" with each array under each heading. Would als0 like to add another heading called Duplicates and code to show what number were duplicated.

Comment: it says WHAT is not declared???? and WHICH `Next`??? There are 3 in each procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a listview is easier and more apropos it's not to hard too do with a listbox.  Here's one way:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox4.Items.Clear()
    ListBox4.Items.Add("Index" & vbTab & "Random" & vbTab & "Sorted" & vbTab & "Unique" & vbTab & "Duplicates")
    For i = 0 To SampleArray.Count - 1
        SampleArray(i) = randomNum.Next(10, 100)
        ListBox4.Items.Add(i & vbTab & SampleArray(i).ToString)
        'ListBox4.Items.Add(SampleArray(i).ToString)
    Next
    Array.Sort(SampleArray)
    Dim distinctNums() As Integer = SampleArray.Distinct().ToArray
    For i = 0 To SampleArray.Count - 1
        ListBox4.Items(i + 1) = DirectCast(ListBox4.Items(i + 1), String) & vbTab & SampleArray(i).ToString
    Next
    For i = 0 To distinctNums.Count - 1
        ListBox4.Items(i + 1) = DirectCast(ListBox4.Items(i + 1), String) & vbTab & distinctNums(i).ToString()
    Next

    For i = 0 To SampleArray.Count - 2
        If SampleArray(i) = SampleArray(i + 1) Then
            ListBox4.Items(i + 1) = DirectCast(ListBox4.Items(i + 1), String) & vbTab & SampleArray(i).ToString()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multi-column `listbox` you better off with `listview`. Set it to show grid, add headers:

```
ListView1.Columns.Add("header1", 80)
ListView1.Columns.Add("header2", 120)
```

For your joint list, pseudo-code:

```
dim myList as List(of string) = new List(of string)
for each item in array1
    myList.Add(item)
next
for each item in array2
    myList.Add(item)
next
.....
' sort if necessary

for each item in myList
     dim isDuplicate as Boolean = FindIfDup(item) ' In this method iterate listview to see if the item exists
     ListView1.Items.Add(new String(){item, iif(isDuplicate, "Duplicate", "")})
next
```